# Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined. Как избавиться?

Tags: javascript, gulp, babel, require

Собираю проект через Gulp. Такая проблема: написал код, после "прогона" через babel выдал ошибку: `regeneratorRuntime is not defined`. Скачал плагин (`npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-transform-runtime` ), добавил его в настройки. Снова собрал проект, но появилась новая ошибка: `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`, так как теперь в итоговом файле babel добавил `require`.
Подскажите пожалуйста как от нее избавиться? Может еще какой то плагин или модуль ставить?

Вот код таска на всякий случай:

```
gulp.task('js', function () {
    return gulp.src(arrayOfJs)
        .pipe(gulpif(isDev, sourcemaps.init()))
        .pipe(concat('GnativeSlider.min.js'))
        .pipe(gulpif(isProd, babel({
            presets: ['@babel/env'],
            plugins: [
                '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',
                '@babel/plugin-transform-runtime'
            ]
        })))
        .pipe(gulpif(isProd, uglify({ toplevel: false })))
        .pipe(gulpif(isDev, sourcemaps.write('.')))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/js'))
})
```

Подключение плагинов в Gulp:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    del = require('del'),
    babel = require('gulp-babel'),
    gulpif = require('gulp-if'),
    sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
```

Comment: покажите ту часть галпфайла, где вы подключаете плагины

Comment: @Vearo, Для удобочтения продублировал в вопросе.
`gulp = require('gulp'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    del = require('del'),
    babel = require('gulp-babel'),
    gulpif = require('gulp-if'),
    sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');`